# Pyserial: "module 'serial' has no attribute 'tools'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyserial

I have some Devices connected to my Notebook via a **RS485 to USB Converter** and want to detect them in a python programm.

I'm running this Code with **PyCharm Community Edition on a Windows 7 Notebook**, I've installed pyserial with pip.

import serial

```
x = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
print(x)
```

And got this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/rzzrgx/.PyCharmCE2018.3/config/scratches/scratch_1.py", line
>   3, in 
>       x = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports()) AttributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'tools'

Answer (score 17):

Wrong way to import , correct it like below:

```py
from serial.tools import list_ports

x = list(list_ports.comports())
print(x)
```

or

```py
import serial.tools.list_ports

plist = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
print(plist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing pyserial (as opposed to serial) fixed the issue for me